# SQL join three tables in a query

Tags: sql, select

[image: Sample-Results]

I'm trying to join 3 tables in my query. Here's the situation:

I have two tables (inscription and fees) that have their secondary key in a third table.

- Inscription
- Bills
- Fees

I can find inscriptions and fees in bills. I'm able to associate an inscription to bills but not able to associate fees to an inscription.

When an inscription is placed, there are some fees applied to that inscription plus an inscription price itself.
BillID can have both inscription price and fees applied.

The table bills is an intermediate. I believe that if I have a BillID I am able to assign the fee to an inscription. But that is my challenge.

```
select
*
from bills i
left join  Inscription ip
on ip.Idinscription = i.IDinscription
left join  fees f
on f.IDfee = i.Idfee
```

When I have IDfee, IDinscription is null and when I have IDinscription, IDfee is null as well. Both bill and fee have the same IDbill.

[results requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfIox.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT
Try running the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM bills i
LEFT JOIN inscription ip
ON ip.idInscription = i.idInscription
LEFT JOIN fees f ON f.idFee = i.idFee 
WHERE i.idFee IS NOT NULL AND i.idInscription IS NOT NULL
```

This query will present you the fees associated with each inscription. I believe the structure of your database is quite organized. One inscription has one bill, and each bill has numerous fees.

Comment: with your solution I am getting records of inscriptions only. no fees. Yes the database is well organized as you said. so it is.

Comment: Could you please check the keys available in Bills? If only transcriptions are showing up then perhaps the link between fees and bills are incorrect. `select * from bills b left join fees f on f.IDfee= b.IDfee` should yield fee information.

Comment: in Bills table. I have Idinscription, IdFee,IDbill. When I have a record for Inscription I will have null for fees vice versa.

Comment: It sounds like you need to join through another link. If what you say is true you can't use Bills as the link between Inscription and Fees. Try for looking for another join table or different column names.

Comment: Please Mr Joseph Cho, the link  see the results. When I select from Bill with left join of Fee https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EZwe.jpg

Comment: Could you show me an image with this query? `select
*
from bills i
left join  Inscription ip
on ip.Idinscription = i.IDinscription
left join  fees f
on f.IDfee = i.Idfee
where i.idfee is not null and i.idinscription is not null`

Comment: Please Mr Joseph Cho, the link has the results of the query you suggested. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfIox.jpg  . your query is giving me what I ma looking for. Mille thanks. However I m facing duplicates issues. distinct is giving me a syntaxe error. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: `select distinct * from bills i left join Inscription ip on ip.Idinscription = i.IDinscription left join fees f on f.IDfee = i.Idfee where i.idfee is not null and i.idinscription is not null` gives you a syntax issue?

Comment: Thank You Mr Joseph Cho. Your query answered my question. I m gonna move my sql result to SSRS. Thank You

Comment: please mark this question as answered by clicking the checkmark, thanks.

Comment: Please Mr Joseph Cho, where is the checkmark that I should click on it?

Comment: should be right next to my answer... under the up and down arrows

Comment: Done. Thanks again Joseph Cho.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this:

```
SELECT b.idbill, p.idinscription, f.idfee
FROM bills b
INNER JOIN
(SELECT idinscription
 FROM inscription
 WHERE idinscription IS NOT NULL) p ON b.idinscription = p.idinscription
INNER JOIN
(SELECT idfee
 FROM fee
 WHERE idfee IS NOT NULL) f ON b.idfee = f.idfee
```

Comment: Thank you Kbball. With your query I am getting only inscriptions records. Fees are not returned.

Answer (score 0):

select distinct * from bills i left join Inscription ip on ip.Idinscription = i.IDinscription left join fees f on f.IDfee = i.Idfee where i.idfee is not null and i.idinscription is not null gives you a syntax issue? – Joseph Cho 20 mins ago

Thank You Mr Joseph Cho. Your query answered my question. I m gonna move my sql result to SSRS. Thank You – Blessed 2 mins ago   edit